# Keryx Installation error

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, software-sources, offline, keryx

### Dependency is not satisfiable: python(<2.7)

What is the meaning of this error? And how do I troubleshoot ?

[image]

Comment: Where did you get that package from? I do not see it in the Ubuntu archives. The message means that the package requires and older version of Python, and so it is not usable on 14.04.

Comment: Keryx is no longer maintained (see the launchpad [page](https://code.launchpad.net/keryx), last update was 2010-10-23)

Comment: @dobey From this link  https://launchpad.net/keryx I downloaded .deb